# Akka clustering and Actor serialization

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to define a ClusterRouterPool that manages a BalancingPool of Actors across my cluster. The actual end Actor that does the work uses the Gson library's Gson class which is not Serializable. When I bring up a 2nd node in the cluster, as it joins the primary node, I get NotSerializableException's thrown on the leader (where the ClusterRouterPool was initialized)

How to work around this? So in order to use clustered actors, every member of the Actors being clustered must be serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Don't serialize your `Gson` object and recreate it when the object is being created:

```
public class Worker extends Actor {
    private transient Gson gson = new Gson();
    // ...
}
```